# Calculating probability of survival from life expectancy table

Tags: probability, discrete-data

Suppose I am given a table of the life expectancies, $e_x$, for ages, $x$, ranging from 0 to 100. Is the following way of calculating the probability, $p_{(x\rightarrow x+1)}$, of surviving from one year to the next valid?

My approach is based on the following picture:

[image]

Starting at $x=5$, the survival rate is 0%, so $e_5=0$.

For $x=4$, we have a 20% chance of living at least 1 additional year, so $e_4=0.2$.

For $x=3$, there is 50% chance of living at least 1 additional year, and 20% chance of living an additional year on top of that, so $e_3 = 0.5*(1+0.2)=0.6$.

For $x=2$, there is 70% chance of living at least 1 additional year and additionally $e_3=0.6$ years beyond that, so $e_2=0.7*(1+0.6)=1.12$.

In general, this implies that

$$e_x = p_{(x\rightarrow x+1)}(1+e_{x+1}), $$

which can be rearranged to

$$ p_{(x\rightarrow x+1)} = \frac{e_x}{1+e_{x+1}}. $$

Therefore, given $e_0$ to $e_{100}$, it should be possible to calculate the probability of surviving from one year to the next for any year, $x$.

Is this line of reasoning correct or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: You seem to be treating years as instants but people die in the middle of years as well as near the beginning and the end

Comment: True. The reason is that data on Life Expectancy (like certain types of financial data) is often reported in discrete years rather than as a function of continuous time. See for example these sources:

1) https://lifeexpectancy.org/lifetable.shtml

2) https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/t1/tbl1/en/cv.action?pid=1310011401&request_locale=en

The question is whether, given such tables, the method I describe for computing the probability of surviving from one year to the next is valid.

Comment: Neither of your links report life expectancy in discrete years, and the first makes my point in the formula for $L(x)$ (also noting that newborns and the very old are more likely to die (if they die in the following year) near their date of birth rather than later in the same year

Comment: To clarify, I mean that LE is reported for discrete ages 0, 1, 2 etc., while the LE-value itself can of course be continuous, as it is a statistical average. With this in mind and ignoring any simplifying assumptions made for infants and ultracentenarians, do you think the calculation described in my question is valid?